# How to pass a list as an argument to typer

Tags: python, typer

**main**.py

```py
import typer
from typing import List

def typer_main(
    channels: List[int] = typer.Argument([1, 2, 3], help='List of channels'),
):
    for channel in channels:
        print(channel)
```

Run this code

python **main**.py

But i get thos error

TypeError: 'default' is not supported for nargs=-1.

Answer (score 0):

It's unsupported by Typer:

> If you want a specific number of values and types, you can use a ***tuple***, and ***it can even have default values***

*(emphasis mine)*

Source: [CLI Arguments with Multiple Values - Typer](https://typer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/multiple-values/arguments-with-multiple-values/#cli-arguments-with-tuples)

There's also an Github issue confirming the problem with moderately weird workarounds posted: [Default value for optional multi-value argument · Issue #518](https://github.com/tiangolo/typer/issues/518)